# Парсинг txt и вывод по шаблону

Tags: python

Есть txt файл где в каждой строке Имя Фамилия Почта.
Необходимо распарсить txt файл, загрузить в словарь и потом через цикл подставить каждое значение в шаблон вида

```
config user local
    edit "ФИО1"
        set type ldap
        set email-to "ПОЧТА1"
        set ldap-server "LDAPS"
    next
end
config user local
    edit " ФИО2"
        set type ldap
        set email-to "ПОЧТА2"
        set ldap-server "LDAPS"
    next
end
```

и так далее.

На выходе будет уже готовый файл с таким длинным списком.
Пример файла для парсинга

```
Pupkin Vladimir pulkin@mail.ru
Ivanov Ivan ivanov@mail.ru
```

Специально сделал отступ от фамилии и почты 2 знака.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте такой код:

```
res = ""

with open("file.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in lines]

    for line in lines:
        components = line.split()

        res += f'fconfig user local\n    edit "{" ".join(components[:2])}"\n        set type ldap\n        set email-to "{components[2]}"\n        set ldap-server "LDAPS"\n    next\nend\n'

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно заставить регексп сделать всю работу.

```
import re

template = r'''config user local
    edit "\g<name>"
        set type ldap
        set email-to "\g<email>"
        set ldap-server "LDAPS"
    next
end'''

#with open("file.txt") as f:
#    text = f.readlines()
text = '''Pupkin Vladimir pulkin@mail.ru
Ivanov Ivan ivanov@mail.ru'''

res = re.sub(r'^\s*(?P<name>.+)\s+(?P<email>[^\s]+)\s*$', template, text, flags=re.M)
print(res)
```